# Create Multiple Columns based on row values of different table

Tags: r

I have a huge data set with customer information visiting a supermarket. I have unique customer ID to each customer and a customer can return to the supermarket any number of times. I want to create feature selection to each customer ID in such a way that I can filter out how many times a customer had visited the super market.

I have a table with set of columns `TripType`, `VisitNo`, `Upc`, `Weekday` etc.
I created a table and converted it to a data frame to calculate frequency. Now I want to create several columns of each Customer Id with more than 2 visits and there are at least 6000 of such variables in train data set.

```
head(train,6)
TripType  VisitNo  Upc  
  40       5       1100
  30       7       1101
  20       9       1101
  20       11      1102
  10       13      1103 
   5       15      1102
```

Unique Id of customer is Upc. Customer 1101, 1102 have visited twice.

```
df <- data.frame(table(train$Upc))
head(df,4)
Var1   Freq
1101   1
1101   2
1102   2
1103   1
```

Now I want to create columns in my train data set of those variables whose freq is greater than 2. SO my desired output would be (Feature re-engineering)

```
TripType  VisitNo  Upc  1101  1102
 40       5       1100    0     0
 30       7       1101    1     0
 20       9       1101    1     0
 20       11      1102    0     1
 10       13      1103    0     0
  5       15      1102    0     1
```

There are just too many features to create columns manually. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution. Hope it will at least somehow help you especially given the fact that no one answered.

```
r<-as.vector(subset(data.frame(table(train$Upc)), Freq>=2)[,1]) 
#selects relevant customers id in one vector.
#If greater than 2 needed remove equal sign in Freq>=2

train[,r] <- NA
#creates columns with selected IDs in the data frame

train[,4]<-train$Upc==colnames(train)[4]
# 4 is the number of columns in your original data frame +1
```

The last line will introduce the data as you want it for the first selected customer. At this point I do not have any other solution than to manually change both 4s in last line with 5,6,etc. for subsequent customers.  I understand it is not optimal if you have many of them. A function should solve it, but I could not figure it out. But I thought that you can pick from here and ask another question about this which might be hopefully answered.